# We need a Poll/Survey Generator for SSD, don't we?

Tags: poll, survey, community, collaboration

Hey people!

I tried to embed a poll in a question without any type of success...

I think it will be useful to have a working poll/survey system to make censuses and generate statics about things like DAW of choice, platform, favorite plug-ins, etc.

Any thoughts about this? What do you suggest?

[alt text http://images.myidol.americanidol.com/myidol.americanidol.com/user/americanidolnow/maar01_polls.jpg?v=113906](http://images.myidol.americanidol.com/myidol.americanidol.com/user/americanidolnow/maar01_polls.jpg?v=113906)

Comment: Heh, just create a question with "What is your favorite DAW" and answer it with "Pro Tools", "Nuendo", "Logic"... and people up-vote the one they like best. It would have to be community-wiki or whatever so the lucky B who types Pro Tools isn't getting 100 up-votes :)

Comment: That's a good workaround, but I was thinking on a more graphical solution showing all the choices at the same time, like a classical bar chart.

Comment: That would be cool.

Answer (score 6):

is this post a poll?  I vote yes!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the suggestion. Regardless of whether it is a good idea or not, it is something that would be hard for me to implement at this time.

I do think the upvote + community wiki is the best option for now. Especially, that it allows for people to give a reason why. I find this dialogue an important part of SSD. The 'why' is just as important as the answer itself.

Anyway, my thoughts, if there is lots of interest I will see what can be done.

Comment: Agreed. It's the 'why' that keeps me coming back day after day. Can't thank you enough for the site @Andrew!

Answer (score 3):

Do we really need polls to know what the favorite DAWs, mics, plugins, etc are?  I feel like most people here are using industry standard items that are very easy to find anywhere on the internet.

I enjoy SSD for the uncommon answers more than the common.

That said, I *do* think we should be able to post polls with a graphic readout - the kind that doesn't show you the results until you've voted.

Answer (score 2):

is this post a poll? I vote no.

Comment: Why not, Steve?

Comment: I like the idea of graphical solutions, I also really like the idea that polls/surveys/resources are distinguishable and answers don't affect the poster's reputation. But basically I was just being a smartass by demonstrating @Ryan's comment from above. So far the masses are in agreement with you as the "yeses" are in the lead...

Answer (score 2):

I vote Yes. We need that.